# How to determine the time sequence of 2 variables in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame - each individual has multiple visits. MCI diagnosis and antidepressant use were captured at each visit. I want to find out the people whose MCI went back to 0 (No MCI) after getting antidepressant treatments, it includes people who used antidepressants before or at the same visit as their MCI==0. In this case, I want to create a new variable ANTIDEP_helped that returns this (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0). Because only patient 3 &5 used antidepressants before their MCI became 0.

```
ID  <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7)
Visit <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3)
MCI <- c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1) 
ANTIDEP <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0)
df <- data.frame(ID, Visit, MCI, ANTIDEP)
```

Comment: If we do not need to consider any edge cases nor other constraints: `by(df[c("MCI", "ANTIDEP")], df["ID"], \(x) { customMin = \(y) { if(length(y) > 0) min(y) else Inf } 
    transform(x, ANTIDEP_helped = ifelse(customMin(which(ANTIDEP == 1)) < customMin(which(MCI == 0)), 1, 0)) }) |> array2DF()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function to check if `MCI` becomes 0 after taking antidepressants and check if any visit where `MCI == 0` corresponds to a visit with antidepressant use or before.
Then you can use the function to create your variable `ANTIDEP_helped`:

```
library(dplyr)

check_antidep_helped <- function(mci, antidep) {
  mci_became_zero <- which(mci == 0)
  antidep_before_or_same_visit <- which(antidep == 1)

  any(mci_became_zero >= min(antidep_before_or_same_visit))
}


df <- df %>%
  arrange(ID, Visit) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(ANTIDEP_helped = as.integer(check_antidep_helped(MCI, ANTIDEP)))

print(df$ANTIDEP_helped)

> print(df$ANTIDEP_helped)
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm creating the variables in piping. Should I create the function before piping?

Comment: Just define the function

Comment: Got it? Otherwise create another MWE.

Comment: That would be great! I don't know how to define a function in piping. Thank you

Comment: I defined the function first then started piping. However, there were only 0s in ANTIDEP_helped. I don't know why

Comment: Okay, just add your example to your question.

Comment: Actually, I got it!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I would think at the patient-level first.

- Did the patient ever receive treatment? If so, when is the earliest treatment?
- Did the MCI level ever drop? If so, when is the earliest effect observation?

If both conditions are met, I would compare the direct association between them. Only if, the effect takes later than the treatment, the effectiveness of the treatment is claimed(Therefore, patient 6 is excluded). So, the actual implementation is as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

ID <-      c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7)
Visit <-   c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3)
MCI <-     c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
ANTIDEP <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)

df <- data.frame(ID, Visit, MCI, ANTIDEP) %>%
    arrange(ID, Visit)

df_list <- split(df, df$ID)

rst_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x){
    latest_effect <- tail(which(diff(x$MCI) == -1))[1] + 1
    earliest_treatment <- which(x$ANTIDEP == 1)[1]
    if(!is.na(earliest_treatment) & !is.na(latest_effect) & earliest_treatment < latest_effect){
        return(rep(1, length(x$ID)))
    } else {
        return(rep(0, length(x$ID)))
    }
})

df$ANTIDEP_help <- unlist(rst_list)
```